# How to access the list of items in a combobox

Tags: excel, vba, list, combobox, userform

What is the "object type" of the .List property of a combobox in vba? I am having quite a struggle in accessing the items when I treat it like a an Array of strings.

Let's say I want to go through the list and check if any of the items match a certain string, how would I go about that?

Comment: does [**`this`**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/two-column-listbox-userform-and-saving-results-to-spreadsheet/) help you?

Comment: is it a ComboBox on an Userform?

Comment: What application please?  And is it a 'List Box' or a 'Combo Box'?

Comment: Hi guys - sorry for the late response. thanks for the link, mehow it did not address my question so much, but was very useful for programming forms in general.

Comment: Yes, it is a ComboxBox in a Userform on Excel.

Comment: Review https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/need-to-loop-through-all-items-in-a-combobox.215899/

Answer (score 2):

Levraininjaneer, I think I might have some help for you...

I've made a windows form with a combobox, a button, and a listbox... The combobox has some items in it, like Item 1 to Item 3, "ABC", "DEF", "GHI"...

[image: WinForm]

Now, you say you want to access the items in your list? Well, try this out...

```
string[] array = new string[comboBox1.Items.Count];
        int itemCount = comboBox1.Items.Count;


            for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
            {
                array[i] = (string)comboBox1.Items[i];
                string item = array[i].ToString();
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }
MessageBox.Show(array[1]);
MessageBox.Show(array[4]);
```

And it will do this:

[image]

And the message boxes at the bottom of the code will display "Item 2" & "DEF"

If you want to "save" an instance of an item in the list box, you can also do it like this:

```
string arrayItem = array[3].ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(arrayItem);
```

This will display a message box saying "ABC" as the index (number in [square] brackets, it starts at 0 generally... So if you put `array [1]` . it's not the 1st item, it's actually the 2nd item... If you wanted to get the last item, and if there's 6 items, it would be:

```
array[5];
```

And also, if you wanted to check if an object contains a certain string, you can always use the .Contains method of a string

```
.Contains("Item")
```

Hope this helps :)

Win10Pro(x64)
Visual Studio 2015 Community 
C# 
WindowsForm project

Comment: Not VBA coding.